# Threadpool configuration on Camel Context

Tags: apache-camel

I have multiple camelContexts created and would like each camelContext to use their own custom threadpool. However, the log shows all my camelContexts are using the same threadpool. What am I missing?

**Main Camel Context**

```
<camelContext id="routeLoader_route">
    (no threadpool defined)

    <route id="RouteCreator" >
        <from uri="file://jsonFilePath" />
        <bean ref="routeMonitor" method="loadJsontoCreateRoute" />
    </route>

    (some other routes defined)
</camelContext>
```

The method "loadJsontoCreateRoute" will read three json files and then create three routes to connect from

1. endpoint "file://xxx1/out" to endpoint "direct-vm:out.test"
2. endpoint "file://xxx2/out" to endpoint "direct-vm:out.test"
3. endpoint "file://xxx3/out" to endpoint "direct-vm:out.test"

**Another camel context**

```
<camelContext id="test_out_route">
    <threadPoolProfile id="outTestThreadPoolProfile" defaultProfile="true" poolSize="1" maxPoolSize="1" maxQueueSize="1000"  rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns"/>

    <route id="outboundTestingRouter">
        <from uri="direct-vm:out.test"/>
        <doTry>
            <log message="Outbound Test -- START" loggingLevel="INFO" />
            <recipientList>
                <method ref="outTestBean" method="dynamicRoute" />
            </recipientList>
        <doFinally>
            <log message="Outbound Test-- END" loggingLevel="INFO" />
            <stop/>
        </doFinally>
        </doTry>
    </route>

    (Some other routes defined)
</camelContext>
```

The dynamicRoute method will return a uri for ftp component

**Log**

```
20160623 09:48:04.297 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.524 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:04.526 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.527 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.634 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:04.636 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.652 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:04.653 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.749 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:04.749 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.827 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:04.827 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.890 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:04.937 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:04.937 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:04.999 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #24 - file://xxx3/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:05.140 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #5 - file://xxx1/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:05.358 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #5 - file://xxx1/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:05.358 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #5 - file://xxx1/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:05.469 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #5 - file://xxx1/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:05.471 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #5 - file://xxx1/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:05.593 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #5 - file://xxx1/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
20160623 09:48:05.905 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- START
20160623 09:48:05.999 [Camel (routeLoader_route) thread #17 - file://xxx2/out] INFO outboundTestingRouter  - Outbound Test -- END
```

Line 3 to line 10 of the log shows that there is more than 1 outboundTestingRouter route is concurrently running while my threadpool outTestThreadPoolProfile pool size is limit to 1

This indicates that the threadpool outTestThreadPoolProfile is not being used by outboundTestingRouter route

What I do want is to limit the max. number of concurrent usage of route outboundTestingRouter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm looks like that should work.  What about the logging statement says your not using your threadpool?

Things to note:

1)  Your route needs to be leveraging a thread pool to make off of the default template.

2) You can always manually assign a threadpool to a component typically with syntax similar to: executorServiceRef="outTestThreadPoolProfile" but make sure you check your component's documentation

3) If your default threadpool profile isn't working you can simply use the standard ThreadPool tag to make an isolated threadpool that can be assigned directly to a component.

Comment: I have edit the threadpool size and the log to explain why I think the threadpool is not being used.

Comment: try with threadpool rule syntax and manually provide the service executor. <threadPoolRule route="*" source="Aggregator" executorServiceRef="myAggPool"/>

Comment: After adding the threadpool tag in outboundTestingRouter route, it works. I think the direct-vm component is using the caller thread, that's why I cannot see the threadpool is functioning.

Comment: Awesome glad to hear you have it up and running!